# Async Await Default behaviour

Tags: javascript, async-await

If you have an async function and have await statements. It states in the Mozilla documents that "If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise." is there anyway to override this i.e. return false from an expression or an empty object to indicate all did not go as planned- or do you have to wrap the stringify functionality in a promise statement?

```
async function sortOutString(string) {

const result = await stringify(string);
return result;

}

function stringify(str) = {

try {
    const obj = JSON.parse(str);
    return obj;

} catch (e) {
    return e;
}
};
```

Comment: why does a function called "stringify" instead parse? what's the goal?

Comment: There is no way to override the functionality you describe. If you want anything other than a resolved Promise, return a Promise from your function. However, in this case, you can just unwrap your function from `try/catch` and add it around the `await` call...

Comment: If what you want were possible, you probably couldn't easily switch to the `.then` style from the `await` style, because you'd need to modify your program flow depending on the type returned from the function.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to use any promises, and you don't have to use `async`/`await`. You seem to be looking for

```
function sortOutString(string) {
    try {
        const result = stringify(string);
        return result;
    } catch(err) {
        return false; // or an empty object, or whatever you want
//             ^^^^^^    to indicate that not all did go as planned
    }
}

function stringify(str) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(str);
    return obj;
}
```

Previously, you were returning the `err` object.